# Tail estimate for $L^1$ functions.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $f\in{L^1(\mu)}$ for some probability measure $\mu$. Pick $\epsilon>0$ and let $A_n=\{x:|f(x)|>\epsilon{n}\}$. I want to show that

$$\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)+\dots<\infty$$

My first thought was some sort of Chebyshev estimate but this doesn't immediately work due to divergence of the harmonic series. Anybody have any hints/ideas? I would like to work out the majority of this question by myself with a small hint if possible.

Comment: Integrate the pointwise inequality $$\epsilon\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A_n}\leqslant|f|.$$

Comment: Ah fantastic, that's a neat trick I hadn't seen before. I guess my mistake was trying to bound each $\mu(A_n)$ separately.